# Как связаны между собой эгоизм и зависть?

Tags: лексика

Происхождение этих слов понятно, но **семантика ясна в меньшей степени**, особенно когда их **сравниваешь** между собой.

У меня есть  **три варианта ответа,** но я не знаю, какой выбрать.

1) Это разные качества.

2)  Они разные, но имеют общую основу (какую?).

3) Одно из качеств основано на другом, является его частным случаем.

Comment: Вопрос по психологии.

Comment: Вопрос о значении терминов, которые могут использоваться как в психологии, так и в обычной жизни. Надо знать точное значение слов, которые мы употребляем. Может быть, зависть - это частное проявление эгоизма, а мы их будем противопоставлять друг другу. Примечание. А теперь еще и злорадство добавилось, получился такой микс из негативных качеств, в котором не так просто разобраться. Связаны они между собой или существуют совершенно отдельно?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что **в основе всех негативных качеств человека лежит эгоизм,** то есть тот первобытный соревновательных дух, который когда-то обеспечивал выживание индивидуума. Различаются эти качества **только по ситуациям, в которым проявляется чувство эгоизма.**

Если соперник повержен и изгнан, то **это вызывает радость** (злорадство). Если он в чем-то преуспел, то  это причина для зависти.  Но все это – **крайние проявления эгоизма**, когда личность не осознает себя частью коллектива, не способна отождествить себя с другим человеком, понять  его чувства, желания, стремления.

А ведь это, возможно, **самая трудная задача**, которую должно решить цивилизованное человечество.

Но стоит сказать, что в настоящее время **чувство коллективизма вообще оттесняется на второй план**. Будь первым, обгони всех – этому "учат" уже бывших дошколят. У меня лучшая тетрадка, я быстрее всех выполнил задание, я участвую в олимпиаде. Да, ты молодец!

**А где же дружба, помощь товарищу, радость общения в  коллективе.** Наверное, всё это осталось в детском саду. И как же  нам воспитать человека будущего, если в коллективе главенствуют идея соревнования и желание быть всегда впереди.

Из словаря:

ЗАВИСТЬ, -и; ж. Чувство досады, раздражения, вызванное удачей, успехом, благополучием другого, сопровождаемое желанием обладать тем, что есть у другого.

ЭГОИЗМ, -а; м. [франц. egoisme от лат. ego - я] Поведение, целиком определяемое мыслью о собственной пользе, выгоде, предпочтение своих интересов интересам других людей; себялюбие (противоп.: альтруизм).

ЗЛОРАДСТВО, -а; ср. Злобная радость, испытываемая при несчастье, неудаче другого.

Comment: Что такое "частные уставки"?

Comment: Частные уставки - это  обозначение конкретных ситуаций, в которых эгоизм проявляет себя  определенным образом (зависть, злорадство т.д.).

Comment: уставка, -и, р. мн. -вок (установленный режим работы автоматического устройства)     УСТАВКА, -и; мн. род. -вок, дат. -вкам; ж. Разг. Команда, подаваемая с Земли техническому устройству, установленному на спутнике, космическом корабле и т.п. У. рассчитана на время включения двигателя. На борт лунохода засылались уставки. Блок цифровой информации для ввода уставок.

Comment: Все из техники, никак не пойму, как приложить к психологии.

Comment: Всё, уставки  убраны и забыты. В психологии есть термин "установки", вот они связаны с ситуациями. Это состояние готовности, предрасположенности человека к определенной программе поведения в конкретной ситуации